# Union of two non empty and mutually exclusive finite sets is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two non empty finite sets. Also, $A \cap B = \varnothing$. Then I have to prove that $A \cup B $ is a finite set. Following is my attempt. Since $A,B$ are finite sets, we have that $A \thicksim I_m $ and $ B \thicksim I_n $ for some $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$. Here following definitions are used,

$$ I_m = \{ i\in \mathbb{Z}^+ \vert \, i \leqslant m \} $$
$$ I_n = \{ i\in \mathbb{Z}^+ \vert \, i \leqslant n \} $$

This means that there is a bijection from $A$ to $I_m$ and there is a bijection from $B$ to $I_n$. Let the bijections be

$$ f_1 : A \to I_m $$
$$ f_2 : B \to I_n $$

I need to prove that $A \cup B $ is a finite set. So, I need to prove that there is a bijection from $A\cup B$ to $I_{m+n}$. Let me define a function.

$$ g :A \cup B\to I_{m+n} $$

as follows.

$$ \bbox[yellow] {g(x) = \begin{cases}
          f_1(x) & \text{if $x \in A$} \\[2ex]
          m + f_2(x) & \text{if $x \in B$}
     \end{cases}  }
$$

Now, I will need to prove that this is a bijection. Consider $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$. Now, let me consider first case here.

Case 1) $x_1 \in A$ and $x_2 \in B$

In this case, using the definition, we have  $f_1(x_1) = m + f_2(x_2) $. Now, since $f_1(x_1) \subseteq I_m $, we have $ 1 \leqslant f_1(x_1) \leqslant m $. We also have $f_2(x_2) \subseteq I_n $, so we get $ 1 \leqslant f_2(x_2) \leqslant n $. So we have,

$$ f_1(x_1)  \leqslant m < m+1 \leqslant m + f_2(x_2) = f_1(x_1) $$

This leads to the contradiction $ f_1(x_1) < f_1(x_1)  $. So, this case is not possible.

Case 2) $x_1 \in A$ and $ x_2 \in A$

This leads to $f_1(x_1)  = f_1(x_2)$ , but $f_1$ is a bijection, so we have, $x_1 = x_2$

Case 3) $x_1 \in B$ and $ x_2 \in B$

This leads to $ m + f_2(x_1) = m + f_2(x_2) $ and since $f_2$ is a bijection, we have $ x_1 = x_2 $

So, in any case, $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$ leads to $x_1 = x_2$. This proves that $g(x)$ is a one-to-one function.

Now let $y \in I_{m+n}$ be an arbitrary element in the $ I_{m+n}$. Here, we have two cases.

Case 1) $1 \leqslant y \leqslant m$

So, $y \in I_m $ and since $f_1$ is an onto function, $\exists \, x \in A$ such that $f_1(x) = y $. Since
$x \in A$, we have $x \in A \cup B $ , so we can say, $g(x) = y$

Case 2) $ m+1 \leqslant y \leqslant m+n $

We have $ 1 \leqslant y-m \leqslant n $,  so $ y-m \in I_n$ and since $f_2$ is an onto function, $\exists \, x \in B$ such that $f_2(x) = y-m $. So, $ m + f_2(x) = y $. Since $x \in A$, we have $x \in A \cup B $. So, we have $ g(x) = y $.
So, in any case, we proved that $g(x)$ is an onto function. This means that $ g(x) $ is a bijection and $ A \cup B \thicksim I_{m+n} $. This proves that $ A\cup B $ is a finite set.

If either $A = \varnothing $ or $ B  = \varnothing $, then $ A \cup B $ is equal to $A, B $ or $\varnothing$. And since $\varnothing$ is a finite set since $ \varnothing \thicksim I_0 $. So, $A \cup B$ is a finite set even if either of $A$ or $B$ is an empty set. So, we need not restrict the statement to non empty sets.

So, does this sound correct ?

Thanks

Comment: Seems correct. What about to use $|A \cup B| \leqslant |A| + |B|$ for any set and then apply to finite ones?

Comment: @zkutch yes that is better option. I wanted to used basic definitions. How would I prove $| A \cup B | \leqslant |A| + |B| $ ?

Comment: Of course here we come to definition of $|A|$.

Comment: I was checking definition of |A| and for an infinite sets, its talking about cardinal numbers. So, we will need to take help of Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem. Is that correct ?

Comment: Which book(s) are you using?

Comment: I am using "How to prove it: A structured Approach" by Daniel Velleman. Author is a set theorist. Book is about introduction to proofs and various strategies used in proofs. Last chapter is on Infinite sets and introduces concepts like cardinality etc

Comment: Let me look it and I'll come back.